# Oxygen Builder Repeater Advanced Query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Looking for some help with a repeater using an advanced query using ACF.

I've got two custom post types: Product, Vendor

Vendor has a sponsored field. Product has a relationship field connected to Vendor

I am trying to sort the Product Archive loop by the sponsored field, so that Vendors that are sponsored have their products show at the top of the list.

I can't for the life of me figure out who that query should be written. It's been like 3 hours of attempting everything to no avail!

This is the code I'm starting with:

```
function solution_directory( $query ) {
    
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'solution' ) ) {
        
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'sponsored',
                'value' => 'yes',
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        );
        
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'sponsored' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '4' );
        
        $query->set( 'facetwp', 'true' );
        
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'solution_directory' );
```

Comment: Can you share some of your attempted code?

Comment: That’s the thing, there isn’t code. It’s a query builder. The way I would do it with code is by creating a variable and using ‘get_field’ to get the relationship field. Not possible here… its all within the one WP_Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer is this can't be done. So instead, I opted to switch up my workflow and create the `sponsored` field within the `Solution` custom fields so I could query it directly.